# how the session ended - session.abandon or timed out

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, security, session

Is there any way that I can fount how the session ended i.e. by session.abandon or timed out or user closed the window etc.
I need to log it in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about any built in function. but I think  programmatically you can do it.
1. when user is logging out by clicking your log out link then you know the way how the user is logging out. you can hold that status when you are clearing session and cookies.
2. but when the session is timed out then usually user's session is reassigned from cookie(if you use cookie). So you when the session is gone and you are reassigning the user from cookie then you know that there is a "timed out" situation.Then you can hold that status as "timed out"

Answer (score 0):

you can check session value on javascript.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var = '<%=Session["session_value"]%>';
   </script>
```